# Pick randomly string from array in C

Tags: c, arrays, random

```
void pick() {
    char* words[2];
    words[0] = "blah";
    words[1] = "hmm";

    char random;
    srand(time(NULL));
    random = words[rand() % 2];
    printf(random);
    return;
}
```

This is my code and I want to pick randomly a word from words array but when I run it the compiler says: [Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared `random` as a `char`, which is a single byte integral value.  You're assigning to it an element from the `words` array, and each of those elements is of type `char*`.  Hence, you are getting an error about trying to assign a `char*` to an integer value.

You meant to declare `random`as a `char*`.

Other things I'll point out about your code:

```
void pick() {
    char* words[2]; // 1
    words[0] = "blah";
    words[1] = "hmm";

    char random; // 2
    srand(time(NULL));
    random = words[rand() % 2]; // 3
    printf(random); // 4
    return;
}
```

1. This should be declared as an array of `const char*` since you're assigning string literals (which are immutable) to it.
2. `random` also should be declared as `const char*`.
3. Using `%` to get random numbers in a specific range traditionally is not very good.  Also see [Q13.16 How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://www.c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)  from the comp.lang.c FAQ.
4. `printf(random)` is dangerous.  If the string you're printing happens to include `%` characters, then `printf` will misbehave (and this potentially could be a security vulnerability).  You always should prefer `printf("%s", random)`.  And since you probably want a trailing newline, it ought to be `printf("%s\n", random)` or just `puts(random)`.

Comment: i already tried that but i dont know why i get this error with char* random: c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\mingw32\bin\ld.exe cannot open output file C:\Users.... Permission denied

Comment: That's a different problem, and it's a *linking* problem and not a compilation problem.  What's the full error message?  Which file is it trying to open?  It sounds like `ld` is trying to write to a file that you already have open.  Are you trying to build while it's already running?