# Interactive story program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, random

Creating a program that makes use of arrays and pointers and takes several inputs from the user (e.g. Name, Age, etc.) and outputs them into a short story. The story has to be different each time the user runs the program however, like this:

**Sample Output:**

```
What is your name? Donkey
How old are you? 30
What is your favorite color? black
Donkey is a 30 year old who likes his black laptop...
```

**Sample Output (second run of the same program):**

```
What is your name? Donkey
How old are you? 30
What is your favorite color? black
Donkey is a 30 year old who likes his black Toyota Corolla...
```

I can get the inputs from the user and output them just fine; my problem is randomizing the events which incorporate the users data. I'm not really sure where to even begin. I've looked at `rand()` but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to incorporate it into my program. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566186/pick-randomly-string-from-array-in-c

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no "do my homework" site.

Comment: SO is a site to help with specific coding issues, so a lot of "help with my homework" questions are on topic. Depends on if the question is specific enough or not. User is asking for help understanding how to use rand(). He just needs to trim out all the fat from the question that we don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to accomplish this is going to be to make an array of a specific set of choices (toyota corolla, laptop) and use the rand() function to choose a random number within the bounds of the array to print out.

incase you want, the following is a tutorial on using the rand(). Just swap "10" for the count of items being added to your array.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/14057-producing-random-numbers/